# How to show that $\{x,y,,z\}$ are linearly independent $\Rightarrow$ $\{x+y,x+z,y+z\}$ is independent does not hold for arbitrary field $F$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers, field-theory

How to show that $\{x,y,,z\}$ are linearly independent $\Rightarrow$ $\{x+y,x+z,y+z\}$ is independent does not hold for arbitrary field $F$?

I was thinking about polynomial space and complexe space and I don't find a working example. Could someone help?

Comment: characteristic two

Comment: consider finite fields like $\mathbb Z_3[x]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about working over a finite field (since simple addition allows you to introduce "extra" zeros fairly easily).

If you pick $\mathbb{Z}_2$, then the following vectors which are linearly independent $\{(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$. The set of pairwise sums is $\{(0,1,1), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$ which is linearly dependent.

Comment: Alternatively, the third vector $y+z$ is the sum of the other two, if the field is $\Bbb F_2$.